# Usage of "Should have"

Tags: grammar

Which one is the right expression? Assuming that this friend is still great today. And for some reason, I regret not telling you earlier about it.

1) I should have told you you are a great friend.

2) I should have told you you were a great friend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is a preference for the subordinate clause to be in the past tense if the main clause is. And "should have" *is* past tense. So if I were taking a test, I would certainly choose

> I should have told you you were a great friend.

However, in informal speech, it is acceptable to use the present tense in such situations especially when the verb denotes an action or a state that is true in the present as well.

> I wasn't sure if the Earth goes round the Sun. (Here *went* would be perfectly fine as well and would mean the same thing)
>
> I should have told you you are a great friend.(Here *were* would mean the same thing).